# AutoIncrement in Couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase

I am using couchbase java client,

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

By using below code am trying find the next incremental id

```
bucket.defaultCollection().binary().increment(docKey).content();
```

I am getting the below error,

> Collections are not supported (or enabled) on the cluster

I am getting the above error

Is there any easier way I can do this?

Comment: What version of *Couchbase* (not CouchDB) are you using?

Comment: Apologies, am new to couchDB, need to check. And is there any alternative Java method i can use to avoid this exception? And does auto increment not supported in older version?

Comment: And the version i could see is 
Enterprise Edition 6.0.1 build 2037 ‧ IPv4

Comment: You're not new to *CouchDB*, you're new to *Couchbase*. They are very different things that have similar names (like Java and JavaScript - common mistake).  Enterprise Edition 6.0 should work fine with SDK 3.x (https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/project-docs/compatibility.html) - I just tried this locally with Server 6.0.1 and SDK 3.1.2 and I'm not getting that exception. Could you share more of the code by any chance? Show how you are creating the bucket, cluster, and so on? Are you using a Couchbase bucket or is it Memcached (or Ephemeral)?

Comment: Could it be an issue with some other dependency pulling in an older version of the client? Try running `mvn dependency:tree` to see which version of `com.couchbase.client:java-client` is actually used.